# JPA entities with different databases - annotations for main database, XML for secondary database

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, persistence, ejb-3.1

I have two databases - new (refactored) and old (legacy) one and I would like the application to run for both databases (not at the same time, the intention is to run application on the old database for some period and then switch some clients to the new database and after some period to drop supprt for the old database). Apparently - the differente configuration, JPA entities-to-database mapping is the only difference.

I know that this can be achieved by maintaining two JPA persistence.xml configuration files. But I would like to have the following setting:
- configuration for the main database should be in annotations (because it is easier to develop and maintain annotations and thay can be placed in the main code).
- configuration for the old database should be in XML file that override annotations.

Is this possible and how it can be achieved. As far as I have heard, then the opposite approach is possible - to keep mapping in persistence.xml and use annotations for overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the JPA providers let you define your mapping using annotations and override the settings using XML files. This is (almost) the default behaviour of any java EE spec.

In you case, you can define the mapping using annotations for the new database, then define a persistence.xml by declaring only the JNDI location and the flag:

<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

Any other mapping will be handled on annotation level.

For the old database, you can declare another persistence unit and override the behaviour declared in the annotations by using persistence.xml or orm.xml.

In your code, you can refer to the appropriate persistence unit by name.